# Dynamic Add Data

Tags: javascript, php

Currently, I am performing an append which I click on a button then it will add a new input for me. For now I have selection which I get from my API. How can I append the foreach data in `insertAdjacentHTML()`?

```php
{if isset($list_country) && is_array($list_country) && sizeof($list_country) > 0}
  {foreach from=$list_country item=valCountry}
    <option value="{$valCountry['countryname']}" {if isset($my_info) && isset($my_info['country1']) && ($my_info['country1'] == $valCountry['country1'])} selected="selected"{/if}>{$valCountry['countryname']}</option>
  {/foreach}
{/if}
```

```js
$("#rowAdder").click(function () {
  newRowAdd =
    '<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 25px;"> <div class="form-floating mb-3">'+
    '<select class="input-field" name="country" id="country" aria-label="">'+
    '<option value="">Please select Country</option>'+
    '<option value="{$valCountry['countryname']}" {if isset($my_info) && isset($my_info['country1']) && ($my_info['country1'] == $valCountry['country1'])} selected="selected"{/if}>{$valCountry['countryname']}</option>'+
    '</select> </div> </div> </div>';

  $('#newinput').append(newRowAdd);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: How is [tag:php] involved here at all? If it is, you haven't provided any PHP code to help reproduce whatever issue you're having with it. [ask]

Comment: @esqew the first snippet lets me think that Smarty is involved, but I don't get how

Comment: when i click add it display this {if isset($my_info) && isset($my_info['country1']) && ($my_info['country1'] == $valCountry['country1'])} selected="selected"{/if} instead of the value @NicoHaase

Comment: @esqew not works when i put this code  {if isset($list_country) && is_array($list_country) && sizeof($list_country) > 0}
  {foreach from=$list_country item=valCountry}
    <option value="{$valCountry['countryname']}" {if isset($my_info) && isset($my_info['country1']) && ($my_info['country1'] == $valCountry['country1'])} selected="selected"{/if}>{$valCountry['countryname']}</option>
  {/foreach}
{/if}   in $("#rowAdder").click(function ()

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section